# Display image to proper portions

Tags: html, css

Hey so I have an image that is being streamed from S3, that image can be any size from super tiny to HUGE.

I first put the style as auto, which worked for tiny images but large ones overfilled the Div

```
<img style="width:auto; height:auto">
```

Then i tried just doing a width of 100% and the large images filled properly, but smaller images were stretched out to the full width of the div

```
<img style="width:100%">
```

Is there a proper way to do this so that large images will be scaled to the size of the div but smaller images will be allowed to display normally?

Solution

@dippas had the correct solution

```
<img style="max-width:100%; width:auto">
```

Comment: use max-width instead of width     >>>  max-width:100%

Comment: try: `max-width:100%; width:auto;`

Answer (score 1):

use max-width instead of width >>> max-width:100%

```
   <img style="max-width:100%">
```